# How to extract the minimum number and for what value it is minimum from a loop

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find the minimum value of k for each i and the corresponding value of m for which k is minimum

```
import numpy as np
    
R0=np.arange(1, 2, 0.9)
m=[3, 7.01559, 50, 13.3237, 16.4706]

for i in R0:
    for j in m:
        k=i/j
        print('%.5f' % k)
    print("The minimum number for R0 =",i,"is" "and is minimum at m=")
    print('\n')
```

I want my output to give me:

```
0.33333
0.14254
0.02000
0.07505
0.06071
The minimum number for R0=1 is 0.02000 and is minimum at m=50

0.63333
0.27083
0.03800
0.14260
0.11536
The minimum wave number for R0 =1.9 is 0.03800 and is minimum at m=50
```

Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1: Naive

You can modify your existing code to keep track of the minimum at each iteration:

```py
R0=np.arange(1, 2, 0.9)
m = [3, 7.01559, 50, 13.3237, 16.4706]

# initialize minimum r0 at infinity to ensure it will be set to the value of an element from R0
min_r0 = np.inf

# initialize min_m to an arbitrary value
min_m = 0

for i in R0:
    for j in m:
        k=i/j
        if k < min_r0:
            min_r0 = k
            min_m = j
        print('%.5f' % k)
    print("The minimum number for R0 =", i, "is %.5f" % min_r0, "and is minimum at m =", min_m)
    print() # print a blank line
    min_r0 = np.inf
```

### Solution 2: Make use of numpy array operations

This snippet performs the math operations more efficiently and you may find it has better readability:

```py
R0=np.arange(1, 2, 0.9)
m = [3, 7.01559, 50, 13.3237, 16.4706]

for rval in R0:
    rval_over_m = np.divide(rval, m)    # element-wise division
    min_rval_over_m_idx = np.argmin(rval_over_m)
    min_rval_over_m = rval_over_m[min_rval_over_m_idx]
    m_at_min = m[min_rval_over_m_idx]
    print('\n'.join([f'{num:.5f}' for num in rval_over_m]))
    print(f"The minimum number for R0={rval:.5g} is {min_rval_over_m:.5f}"
          f" and is minimum at m={m_at_min}\n")
```

### Solution 3: Pure numpy

Following the tip from @mozway to use numpy broadcasting, this snippet divides the array and extracts minimums using vectorized operations before entering the printing loop:

```py
R0=np.arange(1, 2, 0.9)
m = [3, 7.01559, 50, 13.3237, 16.4706]

# get the index of the minimum value of R0[i] / m for i in range(len(R0))
rvals_over_m = R0[:, np.newaxis] / m
min_rvals_over_m_idx = np.argmin(rvals_over_m, axis=1)

# print the results
for i in range(len(R0)):
    rval_over_m = rvals_over_m[i]
    min_rval_over_m_idx = min_rvals_over_m_idx[i]
    min_rval_over_m = rval_over_m[min_rval_over_m_idx]
    m_at_min = m[min_rval_over_m_idx]
    print('\n'.join([f'{num:.5f}' for num in rval_over_m]))
    print(f"The minimum number for R0={R0[i]:.5g} is {min_rval_over_m:.5f}"
          f" and is minimum at m={m_at_min}\n")
```

### Output:

```
0.33333
0.14254
0.02000
0.07505
0.06071
The minimum number for R0=1 is 0.02000 and is minimum at m=50

0.63333
0.27083
0.03800
0.14260
0.11536
The minimum number for R0=1.9 is 0.03800 and is minimum at m=50
```

Comment: Thank you! The first code is what exactly I wanted. I would be using it for other functions as well. Appreciate your help @Noah

Comment: Good to here that worked for you. Note that the second snippet performs the math operations a lot more efficiently, if performance is a consideration. But for small arrays, not a big deal

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a loop, use numpy broadcasting:

```
out = (R0[:,None]/m).min(0)
```

Output: `array([0.33333333, 0.14253969, 0.02      , 0.07505423, 0.06071424])`

Intermediate:

```
(R0[:,None]/m)

array([[0.33333333, 0.14253969, 0.02      , 0.07505423, 0.06071424],
       [0.63333333, 0.2708254 , 0.038     , 0.14260303, 0.11535706]])
```

Comment: This one-liner does not quite answer the question. I would also suggest explaining why might array broadcasting be preferred.

Comment: @Noah I'm giving a practical solution here. Whenever using numpy you should avoid python loops as they are slow. Using numpy builtins enable to benefit from data that is contiguous in the memory and vectorial functions at C speed.

Comment: what I'm saying is that a complete answer requires an explanation especially if op is a numpy beginner. Also, this answer doesn't address the question that was asked

Comment: @Noah I disagree here. You already have an answer on the loop, there is no point for me to discuss this again. Now, I personally think your answer lacks a description of how to do this in pure numpy and I didn't downvote you for it ;)